# How to correctly using mutex in OpenCV-ROS Threads?

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault, mutex, stdthread

I have just started using C++ for some image processing tasks. I want to integrate my RGB (OpenCV Mat) and Depth (PCL) data which I get from ros::Subscribe into colored-pointcloud data.

I use the cv::Mat acquiredImage to hold the transmitted image from ros::Subscribe and then the Mat acquiredImage is used for another processes in another threads, but I am facing segmentation fault. Or the error is shown like this:

> [xcb] Unknown sequence number while processing queue

> [xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called

> [xcb] Aborting, sorry about that. Viewtest: ../../src/xcb_io.c:260:

> poll_for_event: Assertion `!xcb_xlib_threads_sequence_lost' failed.

> Aborted (core dumped)

I have tried using std::mutex but it still doesn't work. Could anyone tell me how to properly manage the cv::Mat in two different threads?

```
typedef pcl::PointXYZRGB XYZRGB; 
typedef pcl::PointCloud<XYZRGB> pclXYZRGB;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<XYZRGB>::Ptr pclXYZRGBptr;
typedef pcl::PointCloud<XYZRGB>::ConstPtr pclXYZRGBcptr;

pclXYZRGBptr acquiredCloud (new pclXYZRGB()); 
pclXYZRGBptr acquiredCloud2 (new pclXYZRGB());
cv::Mat acquiredImage, acquiredImageRotated;
std::thread thread_RunThread; 
std::mutex mutexMutex;
bool stopThread, has_data1, has_data2;

inline float PackRGB(uint8_t r, uint8_t g, uint8_t b) {
  uint32_t color_uint = ((uint32_t)r << 16 | (uint32_t) g << 8 | (uint32_t)b);
  return *reinterpret_cast<float *> (&color_uint);
}

void RunThread(){
    while(ros::ok()){
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
}

void imageReceive(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& msg){
    mutexMutex.lock();
    acquiredImage = cv::Mat(cv_bridge::toCvShare(msg, "bgr8")->image);
    mutexMutex.unlock();
    has_data1 = true;
}
void cloudReceive(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloudInMsg){
    //mutexMutex.lock();
    pcl::fromROSMsg(*cloudInMsg, *acquiredCloud);
    has_data2 = true;
    //mutexMutex.unlock();
}

void StartThread(){
    stopThread = false;
    has_data1 = has_data2 = false;
    thread_RunThread = std::thread(RunThread);

    while(!has_data1 && !has_data2){
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
        std::cout << has_data1 << "-" << has_data2 << std::endl;
    }
}

void CloseThread(){
    stopThread = true;
    thread_RunThread.join();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "Viewtest");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    cv::startWindowThread();

    image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/rsCamera/image", 1, imageReceive);
    ros::Subscriber pclsubAcquirer = nh.subscribe("/rsCamera/cloud", 1, cloudReceive);

    StartThread();
    while (ros::ok()){
        if(!has_data1 && !has_data2){
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
            std::cout << has_data1 << "-" << has_data2 << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            mutexMutex.lock();
            cv::rotate(acquiredImage, acquiredImageRotated, cv::ROTATE_180);
            mutexMutex.unlock();
            copyPointCloud(*acquiredCloud, *acquiredCloud2);
            int i = 640, j = 480, k;
            for (auto& it : acquiredCloud2->points){
                it.x = it.x; it.y = it.y; it.z = it.z;
                it.rgb = PackRGB(
                    acquiredImageRotated.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[2], // r
                    acquiredImageRotated.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[1], // g
                    acquiredImageRotated.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)[0]  // b
                );
                i--;
                if(i <= 0) { i = 640; j--; }
                if(j < 0) { break; }
            }
        }
    }
    CloseThread();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `return *reinterpret_cast<float *> (&color_uint);`: That's an aliasing violation causing undefined behavior. `stop_signal` is not an atomic. Trying to read and write to it in different threads without synchronization is a data race and also causes undefined behavior. It must be atomic or guarded by a mutex. Same for `has_data` and probably others. You can't simply use variables in two threads without considering how they are synchronized. Each variable used in multiple threads needs to be either a `std::atomic` or be guarded by a mutex when being written to _and_ when read.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I'll fix it little by little.